# OleDbCommand Return Multiple Rows

Tags: c#, oledbcommand

I am using the following code to select data from a database in some cases this should return multiple results and I'm not sure how to return all matching results such as all booking times into an array and hen use these in a list box.

```
myConn.ConnectionString = connection.dbdataSource;
OleDbCommand selectServiceNo = myConn.CreateCommand();
selectServiceNo.CommandText = 
  "SELECT ID, BookingTime, BookingDate, Description FROM booking";

selectServiceNo.CommandText += " WHERE BookingDate = #";
selectServiceNo.CommandText += dateSelected;
selectServiceNo.CommandText += "#";

myConn.Open();
OleDbDataReader myDR2 = selectServiceNo.ExecuteReader();
while (myDR2.Read())
{
    bTime = Convert.ToString(myDR2["BookingTime"]);
    bDate = Convert.ToString(myDR2["BookingDate"]);
}
myConn.Close();
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](http://www.troyhunt.com/2013/07/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-sql.html). **NEVER** use string concatenation to build a SQL query. **ALWAYS** use a parameterized query.

Answer (score 1):

Create a class `Booking` where you create all relevant properties, like `Time`, `Date` (why aren't these two combined in the first place?) and `Description`).

Then, in your `while`, create a new `Booking` and add it to a list (`List<Booking>`) you created outside of the `while` loop. Return that list.

(Note: also use `using` in order to dispose your command. You have memory and handle leaks when an exception is thrown before the commands gets closed. More importantly, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. Always use SQL parameters.)